# If $X$, $Y$, and $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ are nonnegative and identically distributed, is $X=Y$ almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative random variables such that the distributions of $X$, $Y$, and $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ are identical. Is it true that $X=Y$ almost surely?

$X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily assumed to be integrable. It is crucial that they are bounded on one side, since otherwise we may sample $X$ and $Y$ independently from the Cauchy distribution.

$X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent because one-sided $\alpha$-stable distributions do not exist for $\alpha \geq 1$. (Proved by [Esseen](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10764) and [Ramachandran](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25049428) in the 1960s.) My gut feeling is that if $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent then they cannot not be distinct at all, but this relies on how, when they are square-integrable, $Y$ can be written as a linear combination of $X$ and an independent copy of it. The proof itself is easy when we assume square-integrability:
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ (X-Y)^2 \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[Y^2\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[(X+Y)^2\right] = 0. $$

I do not know how to proceed without this assumption. I don't think a truncation argument would work since $(X \wedge n) + (Y \wedge n) \neq (X+Y) \wedge (2n)$. Perhaps there is a simple counterexample I have overlooked.

---

For context, I have been reading a paper in which appears a continuous, strictly increasing process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ with $X_0=0$ the following two properties: $X_s/s \stackrel{d}{=} X_t/t$ and $X_{s+t} - X_s \stackrel{d}{=} X_t$ for all $s,t>0$. The author claims that $\lim_{t\to 0} (X_t/t)$ exists almost surely because $X_t/t = \lim_{s\to \infty} (X_s/s)$ almost surely for all $t>0$. (The limit as $t\to\infty$ was claimed to exist almost surely by Birkhoff's pointwise ergodic theorem, although it was not assumed in the paper that $X_1$ is integrable.) I did not quite see how this is true, though I realized that the proof will hold even without the ergodic theorem if my question is answered to be true.

Comment: How about the inequality $\mathbb{E}(e^{-X}).\mathbb{E}(e^{-Y}) \ge \left[ \mathbb{E}(e^{-(X+Y)/2})\right]^2$?

Comment: Thank you! I thought of characteristic functions only...

Comment: Yeah, we were all like that.

Answer (score 1):

If $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is bounded and strictly concave then
$$
E[g(X)] = E\left[{g(X)+g(Y)\over 2}\right]\le E\left[g\left({X+Y\over 2}\right)\right]=E[g(X)].\qquad\qquad(\dagger)
$$
The inequality in ($\dagger$) is a consequence of Jensen's inequality,
$$
{g(X(\omega))+g(Y(\omega))\over 2}\le g\left({X(\omega)+Y(\omega)\over 2}\right),
$$
which also asserts that   strict inequality obtains unless $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$.
In view of ($\dagger$), the two sides of this last display have the same expectation, so they are equal for a.e. $\omega$. It follows that $X=Y$ a.s.

A suitable choise for $g$ is $x\mapsto 1-e^{-x}$.